# Is the nontrivial semidirect product of $C_3^2$ by $Q$ unique?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, quaternions, semidirect-product

> Is the nontrivial semidirect product of $C_3^2$ by $Q$ unique?

This is an extension of a homework problem about group representations, but some of the things I can extract from the group characterization (or perhaps, characters) are:

1. The group $G$ is of order $72.$
2. The Sylow $3$-subgroup $H\cong C_3^2$ and is normal.
3. $G/H\cong Q$
4. All elements of $G$ are of order $1, 2, 3,$ or $4$

Comment: The answer to your question is, "no". The only way I know this is by consulting [this site](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index120.html#order72).

Comment: `\cong` gives $\cong$

Comment: Presumably, $Q$ means $Q_8$, the quaternion group of eight elements?

Comment: @Shaun: Well, you can check to see if $\mathsf{GL}_2(3)$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$, use it to define a semidirect product, and see if the result is isomorphic to $H\times Q_8$, which is clearly one such semidirect product.  As it happens, the second derived subgroup of $\mathsf{GL}_2(3)$ is isomorphic to $Q_8$, so that gives a potential non-trivial semidirect product.

Comment: @Shaun,  I see what you mean.  However, that doesn't appear to meet my condition 4, or the slightly weaker property that each non-identity element of $Q$ acts non-trivially on $H$.

Comment: Thank you, @ArturoMagidin.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question, then, @user156400.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That seems to show that there is a well-defined normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Aff}_2(3)$ which satisfies the conditions I put on $G$.  Whether it is unique....

Comment: @user156400: Well, that's the unique subgroup of $\mathsf{GL}_2(3)$ isomorphic to $Q_8$; you can also try to find subgroups of order $2$ to give you an action, of course, and there are several nontrivial automorphisms of order $2$.

Comment: Shaun is correct, the answer to the question in the title of your post and in the first line of your post is no. If Condition 4 is an additional assumption, then the answer becomes yes, but then you are asking a different question. You should really clarify this by editing the post.

Answer (score -1):

Between @Shaun and @ArturoMagidin comments, you've answered my question.

Let me summarize:  Condition 4 means the semi-direct product corresponds to an embedding from $G/H$ into $\operatorname{Aut}(H) \cong GL_2(3)$.  But the second derived subgroup of $GL_2(3)$ is the copy of $Q$ in $GL_2(3)$.

Hence $G \cong \operatorname{Aff}_2(3)''$

Comment: @JackSchmidt  Fixed.  It's a subgroup of Aff_2(3), not GL_2(3)